# FCL utility to convert XML named entities to numeric equivalents?

Tags: .net, xml, character-entities

Of the FCL classes  (or even using an external API) is there a utility assembly, class or members that can be plugged into a .NET application to convert all named entities to their numeric equivalents?

For example, `&Eacute;` would become `&#201;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) and [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) methods:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&Eacute;");
        s = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);
        Console.WriteLine(s); // prints &#201;
    }
}
```